# How to create a Form<T> for a play (java) unit test now that Form.form() is deprecated?

Tags: java, unit-testing, playframework, junit4, playframework-2.5

In application code when dealing with forms it is recommended to use a FormFactory to create a Form wrapper around the form of type T. But when it comes to testing, what is the way to create a Form? (Do you have to inject FormFactory in the test?)

My app does something similar to that:

```
class MyAmazingClass {
    private final FormFactory formFactory;

    @Inject
    MyAmazingClass(FormFactory formFactory) {
        this.formFactory = formFactory;
    }

    public CompletionStage<Result> myAmazingMethodHandlingForms() {
        Form<String> form = formFactory.form(String.class).bindFromRequest();
        // ... Actually doing something
        return null;
    }
}
```

What shall my test class (for unit testing) looks like?

I am trying something like this but I think I should not try to inject the FormFactory (also it does not seems to work):

```
public class MyAmazingClassTest extends WithApplication {

    @Mock
    FormFactory mockedFormFactory;

    @Inject
    FormFactory realFormFactory;

    MyAmazingClass myAmazingClass;

    @Override
    protected Application provideApplication() {
        return new GuiceApplicationBuilder().build();
    }

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        myAmazingClass = new MyAmazingClass(mockedFormFactory);
    }

    @Test
    public void testMyAmazingMethodHandlingForms() throws Exception {
        String myString = "ciao";
        Form<String> stringForm = realFormFactory.form(String.class).fill(myString);
        when(mockedFormFactory.form(eq(String.class)).bindFromRequest()).thenReturn(stringForm);
        myAmazingClass.myAmazingMethodHandlingForms();
        // Some assertions...
    }
}
```

I am using JUnit 4, Java 8 and Play framework 2.5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say that mixing mocks with the real application is not the best idea here. You should either use mocks (and avoid `WithApplication`), or you can use the "real" instances by calling `app.injector().instanceOf()` (including for your `MyAmazingClass`). For example, when only using mocks:

```
public class MyAmazingClassTest {

    @Test
    public void testMyAmazingMethodHandlingForms() throws Exception {
        Form<String> form = mock(Form.class);
        // setup the mocked form as you expect it to behave

        FormFactory formFactory = mock(FormFactory.class);
        when(formFactory.form(eq(String.class)).bindFromRequest()).thenReturn(form);

        MyAmazingClass myAmazingClass = new MyAmazingClass(formFactory);
        myAmazingClass.myAmazingMethodHandlingForms();

        // Some assertions...
    }
}
```

Testing using the real instances would requires you to do a request, since apparently, you are binding from the request:

```
public class MyAmazingClassTest extends WithApplication {

    @Test
    public void testMyAmazingMethodHandlingForms() throws Exception {
        Map<String, String> formData = new HashMap<>();
        formData.put("some", "value");
        // fill the form with the test data
        Http.RequestBuilder fakeRequest = Helpers.fakeRequest().bodyForm(formData).method(Helpers.POST);

        Result result = Helpers.route(app, fakeRequest);

        // make assertions over the result or something else.
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this nice answer, I like how you covered also the possibility to load the "real" instances (as I also want to make an integration test later), it will be very useful.

However, why are you telling me that I shouldn't extend the WithApplication? How am I supposed to run the test if the application is not started? (java.lang.RuntimeException: There is no started application)

I thought extending WithApplication and providing A GuiceApplicationBuilder.build() or a Helpers.fakeapplication() was the way to do it.

Comment: You can then accept as the answer. So this question won't appears in the "unanswered" filter.

Comment: Sorry, I was still editing the comment (and you have been too fast to reply!) as I wasn't aware that the enter key would have added the comment for me. Please have a look again at it.

Comment: If you are using mocks, you won't need a running application. The whole idea is to test components in isolation. So, if `MyAmazingClass` needs to access the application, you need to mock it too. The second example extends WithApplication because now we are using the real components.

Comment: "you need to mock it too" what exactly? `MyAmazingClass`? because in that case as from your first example I create a new instance of it to inject the mocked `FormFactory`: `MyAmazingClass myAmazingClass = new MyAmazingClass(formFactory);`

Comment: Mock whatever `MyAmazingClass` needs. Looks like it just needs `FormFactory, so that should be enough.